# php settings per application

Tags: php

How I can set some PHP parameters (not Apache parameters) per application without changing global php.ini file?

If I have two apps:

/var/www/app1

/var/www/app2

I need to set different memory_limit, session timeout or some other parameter for APP1 but with no effect to APP2. Is there possibility to use some local config file (similar to .htaccess) in folders that are related to this changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set in `.htaccess` PHP flags in following way:

```
php_flag   session.use_cookies  off 
php_value  include_path         ".:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

Here you have a manual: [How to change configuration settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

```
php_value        name  value
php_flag         name  on|off
php_admin_value  name  value
php_admin_flag   name  on|off
```

Comment: Also can configure the same inside `<VirtualHost>` PHP configuration. It's faster then using the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in apache conf's with 
`php_value` or `php_ini_filename` in VirtualHost/Directory tab